# AngularJS best way to notify a directive inside a Collapsibile directive about a collapse event

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom collapsible directive using an isolated scope, that contains other directives using as well isolated scope, that should react to the collapse event (collapse just change the height)
What is the preferred way for a container to notify a contained element that the collapse status is changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can broadcast an event from your container directive when the state changes and listen for that event on every child directive.

From your parent directive :

`scope.$broadcast(name, args);`

On all your child directives :

`scope.$on(name, listener);`

Look 
[AngularJS scope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)
for more informations on how to use events.